# Где находится скрипт обработчик

Tags: php, ajax

Перестала работать подписка на сайте.
В аякс функции указан url:NameForm (без расширения). Где по идее должен находится скрипт обработчик в корне сайта лежать файл с таким названием, в той же папке где и файл отсылающий на него или как функция в том же файле. где искать в бекапах его, как мне его найти?

Comment: ну так найдите переменную NameForm  где она объявлена и что содержит.

Comment: искал. ее нет. вот в чем прикол. хочу узнать де именно ее искать (хоть приблизительно) есть вариант в бекапах глянуть но у меня нет к ним физического доступа буду просить кого то другого.